# How to reopen an already answered question which is outdated?

Tags: discussion

This question [What are the benefits of a Dual-Core CPU over Quad-Core in a Desktop PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/19406/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-dual-core-cpu-over-quad-core-in-a-desktop-pc) has been answered and accepted, yet the information therein is over four years old.

How can we reopen this topic/question to get more updated information regarding the current state of Dual-Core vs. Quad-Core computing / applications?  I'm thinking that new applications are embracing multi-threading and that maybe in today's world Quad-Cores might be better than at that time.

For those of you in the comments who suggested of a new question being opened, what do you think of this:

> Title: **Do multi-core CPUs still suffer from diminishing returns in
> today's world?**
>
> Body:  It has been shown in [other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/19406/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-dual-core-cpu-over-quad-core-in-a-desktop-pc) that due to the state of computer applications, multi-core processors suffer from diminishing returns.  Is this still the case in today's world?
>
> Do most new applications embrace multi-threading, and thus take advantage of having multiple cores?  If not, do the newer 64-bit OS's help take advantage of the cores by assigning tasks/processes to different cores?  Or do multi-core processors still continue to suffer from the same (or similar) diminishing returns?

Comment: You could offer a bounty, requesting updated information.

Comment: The question it self is out-dated and would need quite an edit for it to be useful.  IMO a new question that is more generic would be suitable: something along the lines of "Benefits of more cores".

Comment: But not so generic that everyone and his dog will try to share their 2 cents

Comment: @IvoFlipse agreed.  I'm looking for more of a [community FAQ](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq) type of question.

Answer (score 3):

The old question is really outdated, and four years in CPU technology is quite long.

I would suggest, like KronoS mentioned, to post a new question in the spirit of [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq), and keep it as generic as possible. We can then close the old question as a duplicate of the new one, thus reverse the process. I like your proposed question and I think we can give it a shot. Tag it [community-faq-proposed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq-proposed) for the time being.

Let's try to encourage factual answers that back up claims with references. A moderator could add a post notice like this below the question:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.